# How to use Appium to Test Dialer Activity?

Tags: appium

If app has a call button on click of which the dialer app inside phone is opened and it starts calling. How to test it using Appium?

Answer (score 0):

Note : Activity name might be different for different devices and OS Version.

Below solution is for Android M with Moto G3 and Nexus 5.

The syntax is :
**Using Appium :**
driver.startActivity("appPackage", "ActivityName");

For your case, it will be :

1.For Moto G :

**driver.startActivity("com.android.dialer", "DialtactsActivity");**

2.For Nexus 5:

**driver.startActivity("com.google.android.dialer", "extensions.GoogleDialtactsActivity");**

```
                       OR
```

**Using adb command :**

1.For Moto G :

adb shell am start -n com.android.dialer/.DialtactsActivity

2.For Nexus 5:

adb shell am start -n com.google.android.dialer/.extensions.GoogleDialtactsActivity

I hope this helps you :)